# What dimensions should images be for an App for iPad?

Tags: ipad

What dimensions should images be for an App for iPad?

This is for a children's picture book; each page will be a single image, and I'll be putting the pages together in Adobe Flash and then converting to iPad format.

So I'm looking for the dimensions that I should make each full-page image.

Answer (score 2):

The dimensions for iPad and the two orientations are as follows:

Portrait:
768 * 1024 pixels

Landscape:
1024 * 768 pixels

Hope this helps!

Comment: ... remember to simply double these values to accommodate the retina display of the new iPad. ;)